# Determine the value of \$\text{C}\cdot\text{L}\$ in a LC circuit

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, frequency, inductor, passive-networks

When I have a series LC circuit, and I want that the switching-time (for the switch between the L and the C) is less then 10 microseconds, how can I determine the value of \$\text{C}\cdot\text{L}\$?

My solution:

$$\omega_\text{res}=2\pi\cdot\text{f}_\text{res}=2\pi\cdot\frac{1}{\text{T}_\text{res}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{C}\cdot\text{L}}}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{T}_\text{res}=2\pi\cdot\sqrt{\text{C}\cdot\text{L}}\tag1$$

Now, it switches when:

$$\frac{\text{T}_\text{res}}{2}\tag2$$

So:

$$\text{T}=\frac{\text{T}_\text{res}}{2}=\frac{2\pi\cdot\sqrt{\text{C}\cdot\text{L}}}{2}=\pi\cdot\sqrt{\text{C}\cdot\text{L}}\space<10^{-5}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space0\le\text{C}\cdot\text{L}\le\frac{10^{-10}}{\pi^2}\tag3$$

Is this right?

Comment: What do you mean by switching time?

Comment: The current will be a sinewave and it switches when it changes from + to -

Comment: draw your circuit to explain.

Comment: "Switching time" is not a normal term for sinewaves - do you mean half the oscillation period?

Comment: You have found how long it takes to fully reverse the state in a LC resonant circuit and how this bounds the possible L and C values. But we have no idea of the application in which you're going to utilize this reversing time. Without any frame circuit this is only a separated calculation. Term "switching" refers that something is wanted to allow or prevent. The calculation as itself is not fully ok. 10 us is 10 ^(-5) seconds as is stated also in other comments and answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An LC resonant circuit has a resonant frequency of \$\dfrac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}}\$.

So, the period of this is \$2\pi\sqrt{LC}\$

If you want half that time then t = \$\pi\sqrt{LC}\$

If you want this equating to 10 us then \$LC = \dfrac{10us^2}{\pi^2}\$

10us is \$10^{-5}\$ and not \$10^{-7}\$.

That's the only mistake I can see.